# git checkout file is outdated

Tags: git, git-checkout

i was trying to checkout a single file from upstream but i only get a very old version of this file. it works on a clean fork so i guess its a git problem

after a git pull --all
i used this command : `git checkout upstream/develop -- system/bootstrap.php`

the thing is we changed a couple of essential files/classes for special requirements, but as the upstream met some of these requirements - i like to switch to their implementation and stick as near as possible to the upstream source.

feels free to ask for more informations/details
( Software: Sourcetree 2.6.10.0, Git 2.17.1 )

Comment: Please show us the commands you used here.  I sense some confusion about how Git works.

Comment: Did you fetch first? `upstream/develop` is a local record of the develop branch the last time you talked to the remote. `git fetch upstream` will bring your local repo back in sync with the remote.

Comment: yes, update the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your copy of `upstream` is probably out of date, `git checkout` can do a lot of things, but one of them is not fetching. Try:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout upstream/develop -- system/bootstrap.php
```

Only `git pull` implicitly fetches I think, so for any other git commands where you are dealing with objects from remotes, remember to fetch first.

[EDIT]

It was up to date, user was using local out of date branch tracking upstream to compare result, see comments.

Comment: ok sry for not notice this - i used the lasted version.

but if switch the branche to upstream/develop i can see the newest commits and changes -> even the "system/bootstrap" file is in the right version. but in the other branche checkout gives just an 6 month old version of the bootstrap file

Comment: "if switch the branche to upstream/develop" This doesn't make sense, you cannot _checkout_ remotes (it will go into detached head mode), but you can checkout a _local_ branch "develop" that tracks "upstream/develop" that may or may not be up to date with "upstream/develop", they are distinct branches. I think you are looking at different files and to prove it, I bet the object refs are different, try: `git rev-parse develop:system/bootstrap.php` and compare to `git rev-parse upstream/develop:system/bootstrap.php`. The one you are checking out is probably the latest.

Comment: To clarify my last point, you have to understand that for every remote branch you "checkout" creates an _additional_ local branch. Your git repo actually has two different branches for one remote branch. e.g when you do a `git pull origin master` it will first fetch into a local copy `origin/master`, then merge that into the local branch `master`. So when you checkout your `develop` branch it's probably not up to date with `upstream/develop`... try it,  checkout develop, and do `git fetch upstream && git diff upstream/develop`. That's why I think you have the file versions mixed up.

Comment: hmm, ok you're right the both commands give me different hashes

Comment: but how can that be ? my local develop branche ( which tracks the upstream/develop ) is up to date and a merge between this and my working branche says only "Already up to date"
so both should have the same hash for your mentioned commands

Comment: If you don't directly contribute to the `develop` branch you shouldn't have a local copy... if your intent is to have it as an "upstream" remote, then you should only ever merge from `upstream/develop` not `develop`, because it does not automatically update when you fetch `upstream`, just like when you fetch your `origin`, that is what `pull` is for, it fetches the remotes, then automatically merges tracking into current branch. It sounds like you should probably delete your local `develop` branch unless you intentionally checked it out to make changes.

Comment: Here's a hypothetical for you to hammer this home: if you are on `master` and `git fetch upstream` then `git merge develop`, you will not have merged any changes that fetch retrieved, fetch does not update your local develop branch.

Comment: Thx for the advice. Yea if fetch find updates I need to pull before merging - but merging is not the problem^^

Comment: Ok to make it a bit more clear for you - for fetching, pulling and merging I use the sourcetree GUI so im pretty sure that these things works fine. Also the command is working well on all other repository - only one specific gives me unexspected results

Comment: It really doesn't matter what front end you are using... if you have fetched `upstream` and you have directly checked out a file from the HEAD of  `upstream/develop` (which is what you describe) it will be the most up to date... your local `develop` branch is different, and that could be for all kinds of reasons, merging `upstream/develop` into `develop` don't make them identical. Do `git diff develop..upstream/develop` and you will see the differences.

Comment: ok found the problem - the upstream url was of an old repository, someone added a new remote instead of updating the old one -.- sry for this stupid reason